# Labels and Buttons in Tkinter Menu

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I created with Tkinter a Menubutton with an image. And I added in the Menubutton a label and two buttons.When I run my application, it works fine until I click two times the Menubutton. It starts to lag and it crashes.

Here is my code :

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

def donothing():
    print("NOTHING")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

Menu_Photo = Menubutton(root)
Photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
Menu_Photo.config(image=Photo)
Menu_Photo.image = Photo
Menu_Photo.menu = Menu(Menu_Photo, tearoff=0, relief=FLAT)
Menu_Photo["menu"] = Menu_Photo.menu
Menu_Photo.menu.label = Label(Menu_Photo.menu, text="Menu")
Menu_Photo.menu.Settings = Button(Menu_Photo.menu, text="Settings", relief=FLAT, command=donothing)
Menu_Photo.menu.Sign_Out = Button(Menu_Photo.menu, text="Sign Out", relief=FLAT, command=donothing)
Menu_Photo.menu.label.pack()
Menu_Photo.menu.Settings.pack(fill=BOTH)
Menu_Photo.menu.Sign_Out.pack(fill=BOTH)
Menu_Photo.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=N)

root.mainloop()
```

I really don't understand what is the problem ?

This is what happens for me :

[image: Error]
[image: Error]
The menu opens and closes every second.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine, you could explain in detail how I reproduce the error you describe.

Comment: I don't know how. it just do like what I described.

Comment: For example what I did is to left click on the image, then the menu appears, then I press the Settings and Sign Out submenus repeatedly getting NOTHING to be printed on the console. Is that what you do?

Comment: What I do is to click the button and then click any where else in the window, but when I do this for the second time it produce the error for me.

Comment: From what I understood, I opened the menu and left click on the image, then I clicked off the image, at that time the menu is hidden, then I repeat the step of opening the menu. For me that procedure does not generate any error. Are the steps I followed are correct? Are you using IDE to execute the code, which is your OS?

Comment: I tried from the IDE and from the Terminal and it produce the same thing and it doesn't give any error message. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I already tried it on a Linux, to be precise Arch Linux, and I have no problems, when you run it on the console does not generate any error messages?

Comment: Very Weird. I tried my code on my RaspberryPi and it worked very well. Maybe it is a problem on my tkinter or on my Ubuntu so I will try to update my tkinter.